# Setting region in terraform local with LocalStack

Tags: terraform, localstack

I am having some issues running `terraform local` together with `LocalStack` specifying `region`.

This is my terraform `main`:

```
rovider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "my_key_id" {
  name  = "/my_path/key_id"
  type  = "String"
  value = "my_value"
}
```

I am running using `LocalStack` and `tflocal`:

```
localstack start -d
tflocal init
tflocal apply -auto-approve
```

**[WORKS]**
I can see the key if I ignore the region:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ssm get-parameter --name /my_path/key_id
```

**[DOESN'T WORK]**
However, if I specify region, I don't get any value back:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ssm get-parameter --name /my_path/key_id --region us-east-2
```

Am I missing something? `LocalStack` keeps creating under `us-east-1`. I am using `LocalStack` 1.4.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi — Can you update your `localstack` Docker image and CLI, and edit your `main.tf` in the following manner:

```
provider "aws" {

  access_key                  = "test"
  secret_key                  = "test"
  region                      = "us-east-2"

  # only required for non virtual hosted-style endpoint use case.
  # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#s3_use_path_style
  s3_use_path_style           = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "my_key_id" {
  name  = "/my_path/key_id"
  type  = "String"
  value = "my_value"
}
```

After a `tflocal apply`, I ran the following command and it was successful:

```bash
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 \
ssm get-parameter \
--name /my_path/key_id \
--region us-east-2
```

I hope this fixes your issue!

Comment: thanks Harsh for your answer! Do you mind please sharing your localstack version? I am using the latest one (1.4.0 at the moment). Thank you!

Comment: I am using the latest as well. My Docker image tag is set to `latest`

Comment: can you also share your docker compose? :) I might be missing some variable

Comment: Did you try updating the `main.tf` file? I am using LocalStack CLI itself.

Comment: I did :) but the issue persists for some reason even though I am using latest version

Comment: Are you on LocalStack Community Slack? We can connect over there :)

Comment: not yet but that's a good idea :) let me join :)